# Update attributes of parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been playing around but I cannot seem to figure out how to update the attributes of a parent model.

I have a model called Enhancement and a model called EnhancementComment associated with it. So enhancements can have comments.

I have this successfully working:

**EnhancementComments Controller:**

```
  def create
    @enhancement = Enhancement.friendly.find(params[:enhancement_id])
    @enhancement_comment = @enhancement.enhancement_comments.create!(enhancement_comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enhancement_comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @enhancement }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @enhancement_comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @enhancement_comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What I want to do:  When a comment is created, I want to update the attribute called :updated_at within the Enhancement model (not the EnhancementComment model).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Updated**

Here is what I have now:

```
class Enhancement < ActiveRecord::Base

# Associations
has_many :enhancement_comments, class_name: 'EnhancementComment', dependent: :destroy

class EnhancementComment < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Associations
    belongs_to :enhancement, touch: true
```

This alone doesn't seem to be working when I create a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `touch` option to `true` on the child association. It's *explicitly* for what you're trying to do, update the `updated_at` of the opposite end of the association on save.

```
class Enhancement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, class_name: 'EnhancementComment'
end

class EnhancementComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enhancement, touch :true
end
```

> `:touch`
>   If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.

Comment: I like the idea. Do I need to specify anything in the Controller? I've implemented what you have and I am not seeing the Enhancement attribute being updated when a new comment is created.